# How write/read Map to/from Parcelable which value is List<BasicType> or List<CustomType>?

Tags: android, parcelable

#### Q1: How to parcel & unparcel `Map<String, List<String>>`?

such as:

```java
List<String> studentNameList = new ArrayList<>();
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("class_name", studentNameList);
```

my answer:

```
// read
in.readMap(map, Map.class.getClassLoader());

// write
dest.writeMap(map);
```

I find it's will crash when `readMap` on OPPO / VIVO, but it's OK on other Phones, and I try find answer on the source code of API 28, I didn't found any order error when unmarshalling.

My simple log, seem as cause the order of unmarshalling, but I'm sure it's OK, and some devices wasn't crash:

```
5 java.lang.RuntimeException:Parcel android.os.Parcel@8a5cf62: Unmarshalling unknown type code 57 at offset 4160
6 android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2849)
7 android.os.Parcel.readMapInternal(Parcel.java:3121)
8 android.os.Parcel.readMap(Parcel.java:2193)
9 my_package_name.Feed.<init>(Feed.java:162)
10 my_package_name.Feed$1.createFromParcel(Feed.java:170)
```

#### Q2: How to parcel & unparcel `Map<String, List<User>>`?

such as:

```java
List<User> studentList = new ArrayList<>();
Map<String, List<User>> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("class_name", studentList);
```